# Struct Values inside Vector Become Corrupted when Passed by Value

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-value

I have the following simple struct:

```
struct Wire {
    int start_x;
    int end_x;
    int start_y;
    int end_y;

    Wire(int sx, int ex, int sy, int ey): start_x(sx), end_x(ex), start_y(sy), end_y(ey) {}
};
```

I also have the following print functions that take a `std::vector<Wire>` and print out some values from the first item:

These functions are indentical apart from the fact that one takes arguments by value and the other by reference.

```
void print_first_wire_value(std::vector<Wire> wires){
    std::cout << "(" << wires[0].start_x << ", " << wires[0].start_y << ")" << std::endl;
}

void print_first_wire_reference(std::vector<Wire> &wires){
    std::cout << "(" << wires[0].start_x << ", " << wires[0].start_y << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

My main function includes the following code.

It populates a vector with wire objects using another function. It then calls both of the print functions.

```
std::vector<Wire> wires = input_to_wires(first_line);

std::cout << "By value: " << std::endl;
print_first_wire_value(wires);
std::cout << "By reference: " << std::endl;
print_first_wire_reference(wires);
```

I know for a fact the first start_x and end_x values are 0 and 0. Both print functions should print these values. But bizarrely I instead get this:

```
By value: 
(-543694264, -543694264)
By reference: 
(0, 0)
```

What on earth is going on here?

---

## Minimum Reproducible Example

(Please excuse the seemingly strange names, this is the start of a solution to a programming challenge from [advent of code](https://adventofcode.com/)).

day3_lib.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Wire{
    Wire(int sx, int ex, int sy, int ey);
};

std::vector<Wire> populate_wires();

void print_first_wire_value(std::vector<Wire> wires);

void print_first_wire_reference(std::vector<Wire> &wires);
```

day3_lib.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

struct Wire {
    int start_x;
    int end_x;
    int start_y;
    int end_y;

    Wire(int sx, int ex, int sy, int ey): start_x(sx), end_x(ex), start_y(sy), end_y(ey) {}
};

std::vector<Wire> populate_wires(){
    std::vector<Wire> wires;

    Wire wire1(0, 0, 1003, 0);
    Wire wire2(1003, 0, 1003, -138);
    Wire wire3(1003, 0, 662, -138);

    wires.push_back(wire1);
    wires.push_back(wire2);
    wires.push_back(wire3);

    return wires;
}

void print_first_wire_value(std::vector<Wire> wires){
    std::cout << "(" << wires[0].start_x << ", " << wires[0].start_y << ")" << std::endl;
}

void print_first_wire_reference(std::vector<Wire> &wires){
    std::cout << "(" << wires[0].start_x << ", " << wires[0].start_y << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

day3.cpp

```
#include "./day3_lib.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::vector<Wire> wires = populate_wires();

    std::cout << "By value: " << std::endl;
    print_first_wire_value(wires);
    std::cout << "By reference: " << std::endl;
    print_first_wire_reference(wires);
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Looks remotely like some [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation in code not shown. We'll need a [mcve] to help you further.

Comment: You have a bug somewhere in your code, and the bug can be anywhere. That's what's going on. And without a [mre] that anyone can cut/paste, run, and reproduce your observations, there isn't much that anyone can help you, here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have updated my question to include a minimum reproducible example

Comment: This is undefined behavior. The shown code uses two completely different classes named "Wire" in two different places. What do you expect to accomplish by defining a `struct Wire` in a header that doesn't have any class members, whatsoever, but then defining a different `struct Wire` in a different `.cpp` that actually has class members, and populating them? C++ does not work this way. Define a single `Wire` class in your header, and `#include` it from all `.cpp` source files.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have made the changes you suggested and now everything is working as expected, thank you. If you write up your solution as an answer I will happily accept it. Are there any guidelines on what should be put in headers and what should be put in source files? I made this mistake because for some reason I assumed that definitions should all be in source files if possible, and so I instead tried to "forward declare" the struct with its constructor, which obviously didn't work out.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Also, should source files always `#include` their headers? For some reason I thought this was to be avoided because if headers just contain forward declarations it's just going to be redundant information, but now I see that is is needed in some cases.

Comment: What you had was not a forward declaration. A forward declaration would be just `struct Wire;` and nothing more. That's what a forward declaration is: only a class name.